# Parsing a feed with rss version="2"

Tags: java, xml, rss, rome

I am trying to parse an RSS feed with Java ROME which has this incorrect version:

```
<rss version="2">
```

When I change it to `"2.0"` it parses correctly. How can I work around this using Java ROME?

I could subclass `RSS20Parser` and override `isMyType` but where and how do I register this new parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a subclass of `RSS20Parser` and by overriding `isMyType`. Then I copied `rome.properties`, added the subclass to the list of parsers in `WireFeedParser.classes` and placed this file on the classpath. I happened to be programming in Clojure and here is the code:

```
(ns feeds.rss20-parser
  (:import (com.rometools.rome.io.impl RSS20Parser)
           (org.jdom2 Document))
  (:gen-class
   :name feeds.RSS20Parser
   :extends com.rometools.rome.io.impl.RSS20Parser
   :exposes-methods {isMyType parentIsMyType}))

(defn version [^Document doc]
  (some-> doc
          .getRootElement
          (.getAttribute "version")
          .getValue
          .trim))

(defn -isMyType [^feeds.RSS20Parser this ^Document doc]
  (or (.parentIsMyType this doc)
      (= "2" (version doc))))
```